# Testing JSON with typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I need to validate JSON with typescript. I wanted to do this like so:

`jsonFile.json`

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "fiz": "baz",
  "potato": 4
}
```

`JSONType.ts`

```
type JSONType = typeof jsonFile;
```

`jsonFile2.json`

```
{
  "foo": 5,
  "fiz": false
};
```

and if I do this:

```
const jsonFile2: JSONType = JSONFile2
```

I want it to throw an errors for not matching types, and a missing property.

I essentially want to make sure two JSONs have the same structure, with one of them as the source of truth. How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)

Comment: This is interesting, but unfortunately not what I'm looking for

Comment: You can't do it if it's JSON. Types only exist at compile-time, and by definition JSON is parsed from a string into a data structure at run-time. If you can convert it from JSON to actual Typescript code then you can do it, for instance the answer below has a way to tell the compiler to treat it as TS code, but anything you want to get the typeof (in the Typescript sense) has to be knowable at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is allowing the json modules by adding `"resolveJsonModule": true` to the tsconfig.json

Next step is importing the json files as following,

```
import file1 from './json/jsonFile.json'
import file2 from './json/jsonFile2.json'
```

Then, declare your type and apply it as you did.

```
type JSONType = typeof file1;
const jsonFile2:JSONType = file2
```

It should throw this error:

```
Property '"potato"' is missing in type '{ foo: number; fiz: boolean; }' but required in type '{ foo: string; fiz: string; potato: number; }'.ts(2741)
jsonFile.json(4, 5): '"potato"' is declared here.
```

Comment: Can you put it in a codepen or smth like this? I believe I have this exact setup, and it doesn't throw anything

Comment: Never mind! It works

Comment: You're welcome!